# Protractor - Safari - Timed out awaiting response to command "sendKeysToElement"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, protractor, timeoutexception, e2e-testing

One of my E2E Test is failing only on Safari browser, when trying to send Text to an inputBox.

```
element(by.css('#content')).clear();
element(by.css('#content')).sendKeys("%20%DCben%20von%20Xylophonmusik%20qu%E4lt%20jeden%20gr%F6%DFeren%20Zwerg%20El%20ping%FCino%20Wenceslao%20hizo%20kil%F3metros%20bajo%20exhaustiva%20ll");  //UTF Text
```

Seeing following error in Webdriver manager console

> 18:40:12.150 INFO - Executing: [send keys: 16 [[SafariDriver: safari
>   on MAC (null)] -> css selector: #contentText],
>   [Falsches%20%DCben%20von%20Xylophonmusik%20qu%E4lt%20jeden%20gr%F6%DFeren%20Zwerg%20El%20ping%FCino%20Wenceslao%20hizo%20kil%F3metros%20bajo%20exhaustiva%20lluvia%20y%20%0A%200c%F4t%E9%20de%20l%27alc%F4ve%20ovo%EFde%2C%20o%F9%20les%20b%FBche%u0E40%u18:40:42.663
>
> WARN - Exception thrown org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed
>   out awaiting response to command "sendKeysToElement" after 30004 ms
>
> (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 30.02 seconds Build info: version:
>   '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50' System
>   info: host: 'vq-mac-dt-036.local', ip: '10.21.134.62', os.name: 'Mac
>   OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_31' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
>   Capabilities [{browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, version=7.0.6, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   platform=MAC, secureSsl=true}] Session ID: null   at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor57.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowa18:40:42.664
>   WARN - Exception: Timed out awaiting response to command
>   "sendKeysToElement" after 30004 ms (WARNING: The server did not
>   provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 30.02
>   seconds

This test is working in Firefox, Chrome Browsers. I can't find any open issue related to safari driver.

Could you please advise, how to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this only time out with UTF8 Content? What happens if you try a non UTF8 string? Also, could you edit your question with: 1. Your OS 2. The version of Protractor you are using 3. The version of Node you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining the clear, click and sendKeys functions on the input box to send the value. I don't think the UTF8 text should cause any problem. Here's how to do it -

```
var ele = element(by.css('#content'));
ele.clear().then(function(){
    ele.click().then(function(){
        ele.sendKeys("%20%DCben%20von%20Xylophonmusik%20qu%E4lt%20jeden%20gr%F6%DFeren%20Zwerg%20El%20ping%FCino%20Wenceslao%20hizo%20kil%F3metros%20bajo%20exhaustiva%20ll");  //UTF Text
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.